# Show image in vue from api

Tags: vue.js

I like to display images in a content in vue. The content ist stored in the db.

I use `vue-auth-image`

If i put the code `<img v-auth-image="`api/media/1`">` in to the template section, it works well.

But whit the following code, it doesn't work:

```
     <div v-html="issue.body" >

     </div>
```

The response from the ajax call is `"body": "<img src='api/media/17'>",`

How can i display the image in the content?

Comment: Add the vue instance code and the result of `console.log(this.issue)`

Comment: any reason why you're using v-auth-image on the first example and then use a src attribute on the second? Isn't auth actually needed?

(Indeed using a redirective within v-html won't work)